# How to get only one field from elasticsearch in the output?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, elastic-stack

```
{
     "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
       "total": 1,
       "successful": 1,
       "skipped": 0,
       "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
       "total": {
           "value": 1999,
           "relation": "eq"
       },
       "max_score": 1.0,
       "hits": [
           {
               "_index": "logstash-2021.01.13-000001",
               "_type": "_doc",
               "_id": "lVef-3YBI8ZVMz0vOphU",
               "_score": 1.0,
               "_source": {
                   "host": {
                       "name": "AAD-W1PF14DMMK"
                   },
                   "@timestamp": "2021-01-13T12:01:19.794Z",
                   "log": {
                       "file": {
                           "path": "C:\\elk\\test.log"
                       },
                       "offset": 158
                   },
                   "type": "test",
                   "tags": [
                       "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
                   ],
                   "ecs": {
                       "version": "1.6.0"
                   },
                   "agent": {
                       "hostname": "AAD-W1PF14DMMK",
                       "type": "filebeat",
                       "name": "AAD-W1PF14DMMK",
                       "id": "4aa46436-264c-40ba-a24a-17af072c8363",
                       "version": "7.10.1",
                       "ephemeral_id": "18c7451e-78a8-4806-b43f-5ebae812b533"
                   },
                   "@version": "1",
                   "message": "2015-10-18 18:01:48,963 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens:"
               }
           },
}
```

I want to get output like

```
{  "message": "2015-10-18 18:01:48,963 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens:" }
```

I tried using

```
GET localhost:9200/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source 
 {
    "_source": {
        "includes": ["message"]
    },
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
        "query": "ERROR",
        "fields": [ "message"] 
        }
    }
}
```

It worked but giving a warning that it will get deprecated by default.
WARNING :

#! Deprecation: this request accesses system indices: [.apm-agent-configuration, .apm-custom-link, .async-search, .kibana_1, .kibana_task_manager_1], but in a future major version, direct access to system indices will be prevented by default

What would be the alternative solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct. The error is related to how you perform the `_search` request.

Instead of accessing

```
GET localhost:9200/_search...
{ ... }
```

use concrete index names -- in your case:

```
GET localhost:9200/logstash-2021.01.13-000001/_search...
{ ... }
```

---

Tip: wildcard index names are supported too:

```
GET localhost:9200/logstash-2021*/_search...
{ ... }
```

and so are multi-index queries:

```
GET localhost:9200/logstash-2021*,logstash-2020*/_search...
{ ... }
```

Comment: Hi, but in that case I am getting other fields as well.
Please check once what I am expecting as output..
I want only to have "message" in json format not hits, tags, score, agent etc

Comment: Keep the query payload -- I was only talking about the URL you were accessing.

Comment: Oh okay but that's the issue.. GET localhost:9200/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source 
When I am using query filter_path it's showing a warning of deprecation.
Any other alternative?

Comment: Re-read the answer :) `:9200/_search` is getting deprecated. Use `:9200/your-index-name/_search`. If there's nothing between the `port` and the `_search` parameter in the URL, you're searching all indexes (tables).

Comment: Oh my bad!! Thanks a lot, man!!
It worked like charm!